# Can't display query when using inner join with php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, web-development-server

I have a drop down menu form like so: https://ibb.co/eX5BhH

Each selected option will filter the query and return the query. So far, my "disability" and "veteran" option are querying correctly. I'm trying to get the "Type of Resource" category to work by using inner join. Here's the sql command:

```
SELECT shelter_name, shelter_address, disability, veteran 
FROM shelter s
INNER JOIN shelter_type st ON s.shelter_id = st.shelter_id
INNER JOIN s_type stt on st.type_id = stt.type_id
WHERE type_name = "Charitable Organization";
```

This sql command works but it only query the resources under the "Charitable Organization" category. The user will be able to choose other category so instead of "Charitable Organization" I replace it with "$value_4":

```
SELECT shelter_name, shelter_address, disability, veteran 
FROM shelter s
INNER JOIN shelter_type st ON s.shelter_id = st.shelter_id
INNER JOIN s_type stt on st.type_id = stt.type_id
WHERE type_name = "$value_4";
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php

require'/Library/WebServer/Documents/Require/require.php';

$value_1 = $_POST["county"];
$value_2 = $_POST["disability"];
$value_3 = $_POST["veteran"];
$value_4 = $_POST["resources"];



$sql = "SELECT shelter_name, shelter_address, disability, veteran 
        FROM shelter s 
        INNER JOIN shelter_type st ON s.shelter_id = st.shelter_id 
        INNER JOIN s_type stt on st.type_id = stt.type_id 
        WHERE type_name = '$value_4'";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql) or die (mysql_error());

echo"<table border='1'>";
echo"<tr><td>Shelter</td><td>Address</td><td>Disability</td></tr>";

//iterate through the table
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

   echo"<tr><td>{$row['shelter_name']}</td><td>{$row['shelter_address']}</td><td> {$row['disability']}</td><td>{$row['veteran']}</td></tr>";

}

echo"</table>"; //close table

echo"success";
?>
```

However, when I use "$value_4", the table doesn't display. If I change it back to "Charitable Organization", the table is displayed again. What can I do to make my table display when I use "$value_4"?

Comment: How large is the data set?

Comment: Hey! It's a small data set. Only about 15 lines. @Strawberry

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: I would just load the entire data set into memory (json) and handle everything else in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think to resolve this issue you should be using `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`.

Inner Joins expect data from the left table and right table to match. If it only exists in the left table but not the right then it won't show the records.

By using Left Join you are saying you want everything from the left table and then if there is information from the right table (i.e. the one you're joining on) then bring that too.

It might be worth reading [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) on joins to help you get more experience.